# What functions are allowed inside <%# ... %> tags?

Tags: asp.net

In ASP.NET, what functions are allowed inside the `<%# %>` tags? I frequently use `Databinder.Eval()`, and I know some basic things like `CStr()`, but where can I find a complete list with documentation? I would look myself, but honestly I don't even know what the name of the `<%# %>` tags are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's funny that nobody really knows what these are called - I think in the ASP.NET MVC team they call them Code Nuggets. Others call them Code Rendering Blocks.

Anyway, this is essential reading: http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickstartV20/aspnet/doc/pages/syntax.aspx

Here is some specific info on the `<%#` Data Binding Syntax: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bda9bbfx%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

And this helped me understand the `Eval` voodoo: http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2004/07/20/what-s-the-deal-with-databinder-eval-and-container-dataitem.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Anything that is in scope. E.g. public/protected methods on your page, public methods in some referenced namespace/class, etc. In addition to things that are related to the current NamingContainer you're within.

Comment: So it's essentially just inline VB.NET code then? Anything is fair game if it's in scope?

Comment: If your answer is true, how come this works: `Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))` **but** this does not work: `Text='<%# Databinder.Eval(Presenter.DataClass, "TodaysDate").ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") %>'` "TodaysDate" is a DateTime object.

Comment: @SpikeX That's because `Eval` returns an `object` that doesn't have an overload of `ToString` with a string parameter. Try explicitly casting the result of the `Eval` to `DateTime` and call your `ToString` on that.